# How to scan only certain areas through the camera with Swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, qr-code

I'd like to scan `QRcode` through the camera. There is no problem scanning `QRcode`,

but I want to scan only certain areas. How can I do this?

I am currently aware of the QR code anywhere in the entire camera area.

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ScannerViewController : UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var qrcodeView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var headerBar: UINavigationBar!

    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.qrcodeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

        do {
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            return
        }

        if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

        if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if (captureSession?.isRunning == false) {
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if (captureSession?.isRunning == true) {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
        }
    }

    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
//        let scanRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
//        let rectOfInterest = layer.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: scanRect)
//        metadataObjects.rectOfInterest = rectOfInterest

        captureSession.stopRunning()

        if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
            guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { return }
            guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else { return }
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
            found(code: stringValue)
        } else {
            print("not support")
        }
    }


    func found(code: String) {
        print(code)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func failed() {
        captureSession = nil
    } 


}
```

[image]

Like the picture above, I would like to scan only within the square area.

I desperately need this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `rectOfInterest` property to achieve this

add following code after  `captureSession.startRunning()`

First you need to convert using rect using

```
    let rectOfInterest = videoPreviewLayer?.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: self.viewAreaOfScan.frame) //  videoPreviewLayer is AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
```

after that you can assign it to `rectOfInterest`  of `metadataOutput`

```
    metadataOutput.rectOfInterest = rectOfInterest ?? CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
```

Comment: What is `viewAreaOfScan`??

Comment: @iosbegindevel You can directly pass CGRect object there into fromLayerRect

Comment: Don't I need to assign a value to the RectOfInterest variable as stated above?

Comment: @iosbegindevel You need to convert in using  `metadataOutputRectConverted` otherwise it won't work

Comment: Okay, but I don't have a variable called viewAreaOfScan. Where does this come from?   I know little about Swift. Please understand

Comment: @iosbegindevel I have custom view in center which is the area should be used for scanning.  you can provide your rect like this  example      `let rectOfInterest = videoPreviewLayer?.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: CGRect(x:10,y:10,width:300,height:300)`

Comment: Thanks you so much~

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5
A very powerfull answer after spending complete day

its will work in your required view like i am using viewCamera you can use your own UI as you like

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewCamera: UIView!

var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadCameraForQRCodeScanning()
}

func loadCameraForQRCodeScanning() {
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
    
    let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput
    
    do {
        videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
    } catch {
        return
    }

    if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
        captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
    } else {
        failed()
        return
    }

    let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

    if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
        captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
    } else {
        failed()
        return
    }
    
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer.frame = viewCamera.bounds
    previewLayer.videoGravity = .resize
    viewCamera.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    
    captureSession.startRunning()
}
```

Comment: The question is asking how to limit the scan area to a specific rectangle. Your answer does not explain how it solves that problem. Please do not post code-only answers.